# Count unique value for each group and subtotal

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a simple dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'BR_NM': ['HN', 'HN', 'HP'], 
                   'CUS_ID': ['12345', '12345', '12345'],
                   'ACC_ID': ['12345_1', '12345_2', '12345_3'],
                   'REGION': ['North', 'North', 'North'], 
                   'CUS_TYPE': ['Individual', 'Individual', 'Individual']})
df
BR_NM   CUS_ID  ACC_ID  REGION  CUS_TYPE
HN      12345   12345_1 North   Individual
HN      12345   12345_2 North   Individual
HP      12345   12345_3 North   Individual
```

I want to count unique `CUS_ID` based on `BR_NM` then sum it based on `REGION`. In my case, it's just one customer with three account but I want to count it as two customer. Below is my desired Ouput:

```
REGION  CUS_TYPE    North
0      Individual   2
```

If I used `pivot_table` and `aggfunc = pd.Series.nunique` it just count as 1.

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='CUS_ID', columns='REGION', index='CUS_TYPE', aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique).reset_index()
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think your example is not very helpful in trying to understand what you are looking for. 
Can you provide an example with a bit more variety?

Comment: Not really sure how you're getting from you starting material into your expected output, but have you tried something like `df.groupby("BR_NM").nunique()[`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's just one customer with three account but I want to count it as two customer.

Use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) based on `BR_NM` and `CUS_ID` columns to get unique records:

```
>>> (df.drop_duplicates(['BR_NM', 'CUS_ID'])
       .value_counts(['REGION', 'CUS_TYPE'])
       .unstack('REGION').reset_index())

REGION    CUS_TYPE  North
0       Individual      2
```

About `drop_duplicates`:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(['BR_NM', 'CUS_ID'])

  BR_NM CUS_ID   ACC_ID REGION    CUS_TYPE
0    HN  12345  12345_1  North  Individual
2    HP  12345  12345_3  North  Individual
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way this can be achieved by performing a group-by operation, then followed by counting unique values and then summing these counts.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'BR_NM': ['HN', 'HN', 'HP', 'HP', 'HA', 'HA'], 
                   'CUS_ID': ['12345', '12345', '12345', '12345', '12346', '12347'],
                   'ACC_ID': ['12345_1', '12345_2', '12345_3', '12345_4', '12345_5', '12345_6'],
                   'REGION': ['North', 'North', 'North', 'South', 'South', 'West'], 
                   'CUS_TYPE': ['Individual', 'Individual', 'Individual', 'Individual', 'Individual', 'Individual']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Count unique CUS_ID based on BR_NM and REGION
counts = df.groupby(['REGION', 'BR_NM'])['CUS_ID'].nunique().reset_index()

# Sum counts based on REGION
result = counts.groupby('REGION')['CUS_ID'].sum().reset_index()
result.columns = ['REGION', 'COUNT']

print(result)
```

output:

```
  REGION  COUNT
0  North      2
1  South      2
2   West      1
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but accepted answer is simpler.